# Java Spring pagination and filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I need to implement filtering functionality for customer data. I've set up a **CustomerRepository** with a custom method named **findByName** to handle the filtering based on specific criteria such as **first_name** and **last_name**. However, when I try to use this custom method in both my **CustomerService** and **CustomerController**, I'm encountering an issue during application startup. The error message indicates that Spring Data JPA is unable to recognize the findByName method as a valid query method and it mentions a missing property that isn't present in my Customer entity.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerRepository'

Customer.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String first_name;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last_name;
    
    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;
    
    
    /** Getter and Setter **/
}
```

CustomerRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository <Customer, Integer>{

    Page<Customer> findByName(String firstName, String lastName, Pageable pageable);
}
```

CustomerService.java:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    public Page<Customer> searchCustomers(String firstName, String lastName, Pageable pageable) {
        return customerRepository.findByName(firstName, lastName, pageable);
    }
}
```

CustomerController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
    
    @GetMapping("/pagination")
    public Page<Customer> searchCustomers(
              @RequestParam(required = false) String firstName,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String lastName,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int pageSize)
    {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize);
        return customerService.searchCustomers(firstName, lastName, pageable);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should post the whole stacktrace. Moreover, the field name is first_name and not firstName.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct because there is indeed no `name` field in your entity. You only have `first_name` and `last_name`.

Moreover, you have not followed the java naming convention to name your entity fields.

The correct convention will be to rename them as:

```
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
```

Then you can query by `firstName` and `lastName` as `findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName, lastName, pageable)`.